# invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::promise<int>’ error while compile using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-5

Tags: c++11, arm

I am getting error while compiling the below code for arm using 
          arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-5 filename.cpp -std=c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

void initiazer(std::promise<int> * promObj)
{
    std::cout<<"Inside Thread"<<std::endl;     promObj->set_value(35);
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> promiseObj;
    std::future<int> futureObj = promiseObj.get_future();
    std::thread th(initiazer, &promiseObj);
    std::cout<<futureObj.get()<<std::endl;
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

> **Error :**
>
> test.cpp: In function ‘void initiazer(std::promise*)’:
>   test.cpp:10:55: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class
>   std::promise’
>        std::cout<<"Inside Thread"<set_value(35);
>                                                          ^ In file included from test.cpp:4:0:
>   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/5/future:124:11: note: declaration
>   of ‘class std::promise’
>        class promise;
>              ^ test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:15:23: error: aggregate ‘std::promise promiseObj’ has incomplete type
>   and cannot be defined
>        std::promise promiseObj;
>                          ^ test.cpp:16:22: error: variable ‘std::future futureObj’ has initializer but incomplete type
>        std::future futureObj = promiseObj.get_future();

Comment: You need to upgrade your compiler, on [this page](https://godbolt.org/) you can choose particular ARM gcc version and check whether your code compiles, since *arm gcc 7.3* it compiles fine.